# How to wait after request before loading with soup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to request to the website the request works and I can load it

but what I am trying to get from the website is not revived from there server as seen here:

[Loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U89XI.png)

How would I fix this?

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://9xbuddy.com/process?url=https://streamango.com/embed/accssmlbkfmmsrcd')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

links = [items.get('href') for items in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'leading-normal sm:leading-none block sm:inline-block bg-blue px-6 sm:px-12 lg:px-6 py-2 text-white no-underline shadow hover:opacity-75'})]
print(links) #[] page sill loading
```

Comment: Use a method like selenium to automate a browser

Comment: Could you please post your code

Comment: You need to find the request that actually contains the data you want. Then just request that directly. Always use `selenium` as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issued a GET, and parsed its result, just fine.
But you didn't ask for the final document you want.
You asked for an initial loader that starts some JS webpack delayed loading.

If you can map from initial URL to the final document you care about,
write a function for that.
Otherwise, if you need the assistance of javascript interpretation of site logic
to find the final URL, you may want to resort to [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).